# Why Does Serial.println(<char[]>); Return Random Characters?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, serialization, arduino

I am wracking my brain trying to solve this one. 
For starters:
*My baudrate is 9600 on both ends.
*I have an array of size 8, so max index is 7
*I set each char (positions 0,1,3,4,6,7) in the array to a number 0-9 based on time
*If I print the time, it comes out perfectly except when the number is above 18:00:00
*The const longs for MSin1Hr, MSin24Hr, etc are declared globally
Below is the code that gets the time from MS to string

```
char lightOffTime[] = {'0', '0', ':', '0', '0', ':', '0', '0'};

void getTimeStr(char inArr[], unsigned long timeInMS)
{
  int num = 0;
  char cstr[16];

  num = timeInMS / (10 * MSin1Hr); //tens of hours
  sprintf(cstr, "%01d", num);
  inArr[0] = cstr[0];

  num = timeInMS % (10 * MSin1Hr) / MSin1Hr; //remainder
  sprintf(cstr, "%01d", num);
  inArr[1] = cstr[0];

  unsigned long minutesMS = timeInMS % MSin1Hr;
  num = minutesMS / (10 * MSin1Minute); //tens of minutes
  sprintf(cstr, "%01d", num);
  inArr[3] = cstr[0];

  num = minutesMS % (10 * MSin1Minute) / MSin1Minute; //remainder
  sprintf(cstr, "%01d", num);
  inArr[4] = cstr[0];

  unsigned long secondsMS = timeInMS % MSin1Minute;
  num = secondsMS / 10000; //tens of seconds
  sprintf(cstr, "%01d", num);
  inArr[6] = cstr[0];

  num = (secondsMS % 10000) / 1000; //remainder
  sprintf(cstr, "%01d", num);
  inArr[7] = cstr[0];
}
```

I call the function using

```
getTimeStr(lightOffTime, lightTurnOffTime);
```

Then I can print it to the Serial using `Serial.println(lightOffTime);`

As you can see, I simply pass in the array and the time in MS and it should pop out the time as a formatted string. Any ideas? -the specific number I am passing in is 68401000 (19:00:01) which for some reason is printing 19:00:01h

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to call this function, including the declaration for the array?

Comment: Added, in the meantime got downvoted xD

Comment: Is the array used as a string? If so you don't have a nul char `\0` at the end

Comment: so should the array actually be char lightOffTime[] = {'0', '0', ':', '0', '0', ':', '0', '0', '\0'};?

Edit: I don't think I am, I just pass it as an array straight to the println, and the error only happens if the number is > 19:00:00 as well

Comment: Edit 2: I just tried that and it does work correctly now, but WHY? lol

Comment: @ComputerTuts How were you expecting `println` to know how many bytes to send?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use a single sprintf ? `sprintf(inarr, "%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);`

Comment: The main reason was that I didn't think of that, thank you all! I thought that sizeof would automatically know I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have a null terminator at the end of your string to tell the print function where to stop printing.  It probably just so happened that the next spot in memory just happened to have a 0 in it until you got to that particular number and for whatever reason there ended up being an h right after your array in memory in that case, and then obviously a 0 right after that since it stopped there.

So the fact that it worked with other numbers was just a fluke.  Sometimes bugs are like that, you make an error and for whatever reason it appears to work fine in some cases.  That's the nature of running off the end of an array.  They call it "undefined behavior" because there is no way to predict what will happen when you do this.